# php passing a variable from web address to display property

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to set a display behavior based on what the address is...
`people.php?group=inline-block`

```
<?php
$_GET["group1"];
$_GET["group2"];
$_GET["group3"];
$_GET["group4"];
$_GET["group5"];
?>
```

here is the html:

```
<div id="bordercolor" style"display=<?php echo $_GET["group1"]
?>;
```

Now here's the problem... I want the default to be display:none; however whatever group it is it means `inline-block` and I want the none to be replace with inline block.

Could a simple echo exist and just put the default in the external style sheet? Or better yet how can I achieve my goal?

Cheers... William

Comment: If you're passing styles around your URL, you should reevaluate the issue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check your input before echoing it to prevent any unwanted injected code.

```
$acceptedDisplayValues = ['none', 'inline', 'inline-block'];
//Checks if $_GET['group'] is set, if not echo default value.
//If it is set, check if the value is allowed, if not, echo default value.
echo((isset($_GET['group']) ? (in_array($_GET['group'], $acceptedDisplayValues) ? $_GET['group'] : 'none') : 'none'));
```

Comment: thank you... I sort of understand where you are coming from and thanks for the accepted display values I've been reading about the vulnerabilities of $_get and was worried... Thanks again..